# Need to Insert Multiple Data by selecting Checkboxes

Tags: php, pdo

I need to Insert data to the DB using the form given below

```
<form action="OtherEventPayment.php" id="frmSignIn" method="post">  
    <input  type="hidden" name="online_id" value="<?php echo $lid; ?>" >        
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>No. of Participants</th>
            <th>Tick the Items</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tbody>

<?php
$sn ="1";
$id = $oth_event_id;
$stmt1 = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM oth_events_details 
                            LEFT JOIN oth_event_category ON (oth_events_details.oth_evcat_id=oth_event_category.oth_evcat_id)
                            WHERE oth_event_id =:uid ORDER BY oth_event_det_id DESC');
$stmt1->execute(array(':uid'=>$id));
$stmt1->execute();
if($stmt1->rowCount() > 0)
{
    while($row1=$stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))

    {

        extract($row1);
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $sn; ?></td>
        <td>

        <?php  echo $row1['oth_category'];?> -
        <?php 

          $group =$row1['oth_catgroup_type']; 
                    if ($group=="S")
                    {
                        echo "Single";
                    }
                    elseif ($group=="D")
                    {
                        echo "Doubles";
                    }
                    else{

                        echo "Group";

                    }


        ?>

        </td>

        <td><?php echo $row1['participntno']; ?></td>

        <td>
        <b>



        </b>

        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[<?php echo $row1['oth_event_det_id'];?>]" value="<?php echo $row1['oth_event_det_id'];?>" id="chk[<?php echo $row1['oth_event_det_id'];?>]" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fees:-&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row1['oth_ev_fee'];?>

        </td>




        </tr>
        <?php $sn++; ?>

        <?php
    }
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }

    ?>  

    </tbody>


    </table>        
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="submit" name="selectItems" value="Submit & Proceed" class="btn btn-primary pull-right mb-xl" data-loading-text="Loading...">
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $sn1=$sn-1; ?>
    </form>
```

in the OtherEventPayment.php i have written the code. But not working . How to Insert data correctly to DB

```
<?php
```

require_once 'dbconfig.php';

if(isset($_POST['selectItems']))
{

echo array[] = $_POST['chk[]'];

echo $oth_online_id= $_POST['online_id'];

```
if($oth_event_detid != ""){
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($oth_event_detid);$i++)
{
```

// oth_event_det_id,oth_online_id

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO othevents_itemsonline(oth_event_det_id,oth_online_id) VALUES( :oth_event_det_id, :oth_online_id)');
$stmt->bindParam(':oth_event_det_id',$oth_event_det_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':oth_online_id',$oth_online_id);  


if($stmt->execute())
        {
            $lastonlineid= $DB_con->lastInsertId(); 

            $successMSG = "Thank you For Registering with us . Please select the items to be participating...";

            // header("refresh:0;OtherEventsOnlineRegistrationThankyou.php"); /
        }
        else
        {
            $errMSG = "error while registering....";
        } } }



}
```

?>

Comment: Please format your code properly, this is a mess. It is hard to help you, if you don't clean-up your code.

Answer (score 2):

Name should be same for input field. Use following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="<?php echo $row1['oth_event_det_id'];?>" id="chk[<?php echo $row1['oth_event_det_id'];?>]" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fees:-&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row1['oth_ev_fee'];?>
```

You can see name. Hopefully it will be clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value of you checkboxes and the value it represents but keep the name same with the others, yet it should have a name with []

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk<?php echo $row1['oth_event_det_id'];?>" name="chk[]" value="<?php echo $row1['oth_event_det_id'];?>">
<label for="chk<?php echo $row1['oth_event_det_id'];?>"><?php echo $row1['oth_event_det_id'];?></label>
```

having a name chk[] like this will send and serve as an array in your get or post-function so loop it on controller or function that will add it in the DB

upon inserting it,

```
$data = $_GET['chk']; //this is in array form
foreach($data as $chk){
//insert code here
}
```

Comment: it showing the error Notice: Undefined index: chk[] in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\NEWSICASA\OtherEventPayment.php on line 11
80
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'oth_event_det_id' cannot be null' in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\NEWSICASA\OtherEventPayment.php:24 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\NEWSICASA\OtherEventPayment.php(24): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\NEWSICASA\OtherEventPayment.php on line 24